# Given two sets $A$ and $B$, is it true that $|B^A|=\max\{|B|,|\mathcal{P}(A)|\}$?

Tags: cardinals

My intuition is that this is true, because it makes sense for little sets (with cardinalities $|\mathbb{N}|,|2^\mathbb{N}|$). But i'm not sure at all that this is actually true.

If it's not, what's the real relation between $|B^A|$ and $|B|,|A|$.

(Obviously talking about infinite sets)

Comment: I've already proved that if $|B|\leq|A|$ then $|B^A|=|\mathcal{P}(A)|$.

Comment: If the notation "B^A" ever seemed weird to you (as it did to me) it's worth speculating about why somebody may have chosen it. (It almost seems like a trick question, but it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

Surely not true for finite sets. Counterexample

$$A=\{1,2\} \text{ and } B = \{1,2,3\}.$$

And if [Singular cardinals hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_cardinals_hypothesis) is assumed, the result is again wrong as

$$\text{if } \vert \mathcal P(A) \vert \lt \vert B \vert \text{ and } \text{cf} \vert B \vert \le \vert A \vert \text{ then } \vert B^A \vert = \vert B \vert^+$$

Comment: Edited the post, just referring to infinite sets.

Comment: Still wrong at least assuming SCH.